# Uncaught ReferenceError: openerp is not defined in odoo v10

Tags: javascript, odoo-10

I am having the error while installing a module in odoo v10 . The js file starts like this:

```
openerp.my_module_name = function(instance) {
           console.log('Something');
}
```

In browser console this error shows:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: openerp is not defined

It works in other versions of odoo. What has changed and how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
odoo.my_module_name = function(instance) {
       console.log('Something');
}
```

Comment: I tried this but nothing happens. It doesn't execute the js.

Answer (score 0):

To execute js from your custom module in v10 you need to do like this:

`odoo.define('your_module_name.file_name', function (require) {
  "use strict";
   console.log('Something');
});`

In odoov10 no need to create instance like openerp.